# When running Elixir container bootstrap I get Error loading module pooler_app, how can I solve that?

Tags: docker, erlang, elixir

I'm running a container with an Elixir application, but when I try to make a bootstrap I get the following error:

> 12:49:59.687 [error] beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module pooler_app:
>     This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 20.
>     To fix this, please recompile this module with an 20 compiler.
>     (Use of opcode 164; this emulator supports only up to 159.)
>
> 12:49:59.707 [info]  Application pooler exited: exited in: :pooler_app.start(:normal, [])
>       ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
>           ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :pooler_app.start/2 is undefined (module :pooler_app is not available)
>               (pooler) :pooler_app.start(:normal, [])
>               (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
>   ** (ArgumentError) argument error
>       (stdlib) :ets.lookup(:cqerl_clusters, :system)
>       (cqerl) /mnt/svcs/lukla/deps/cqerl/src/cqerl_cluster.erl:52: :cqerl_cluster.get_any_client/1
>       lib/cassandra.ex:50: Lukla.Cassandra.new_client/1
>       lib/cassandra.ex:11: Lukla.Cassandra.new!/1
>       lib/mix/tasks/cassandra.drop.ex:16: Mix.Tasks.Cassandra.Drop.run/1
>       (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:314: Mix.Task.run_task/3
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum.each/2

I tried to change the Elixir version and Erlang version, but the error persists.

I'm using `asdf` with Elixir 1.6.5 and Erlang 20.0.

#### Edit

I deleted my `_build` folder, now when I try the bootstrap again I get the following error:

> 14:17:44.539 [error] Loading of /mnt/svcs/lukla/_build/dev/lib/re2/ebin/re2.beam failed: :badfile
>
> 14:17:44.539 [error] beam/beam_load.c(1863): Error loading module re2:
>     This BEAM file was compiled for a later version of the run-time system than 20.
>     To fix this, please recompile this module with an 20 compiler.
>     (Use of opcode 164; this emulator supports only up to 159.)
>
> ** (exit) exited in: :gen_fsm.sync_send_event(#PID<0.360.0>, {:send_query, #Reference<0.2121126444.1751646212.63871>, {:cql_query, "DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS lukla_dev;", [], :undefined, false, 100, :undefined, :one, :undefined, :undefined}}, 5000)
>       ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
>           ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :re2.compile/1 is undefined (module :re2 is not available)
>               (re2) :re2.compile('\'*(\?|:\w+)\'*(?:(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)')
>               (cqerl) /mnt/svcs/lukla/deps/cqerl/src/cqerl_cache.erl:58: :cqerl_cache.lookup/2
>               (cqerl) /mnt/svcs/lukla/deps/cqerl/src/cqerl_client.erl:244: :cqerl_client.live/3
>               (stdlib) gen_fsm.erl:483: :gen_fsm.handle_msg/8
>               (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:247: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
>       (stdlib) gen_fsm.erl:252: :gen_fsm.sync_send_event/3
>       (cqerl) /mnt/svcs/lukla/deps/cqerl/src/cqerl.erl:196: :cqerl.run_query/3
>       lib/cqex/query.ex:62: CQEx.Query.call/2
>       lib/cqex/query.ex:75: CQEx.Query.call!/2
>       lib/mix/tasks/cassandra.drop.ex:18: Mix.Tasks.Cassandra.Drop.run/1
>       (mix) lib/mix/task.ex:314: Mix.Task.run_task/3
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum."-each/2-lists^foreach/1-0-"/2
>       (elixir) lib/enum.ex:737: Enum.each/2
>
> 14:17:44.572 [error] ** State machine #PID<0.360.0> terminating 
>   ** Last message in was {:"$gen_sync_event", {#PID<0.74.0>, #Reference<0.2121126444.1751646212.63875>}, {:send_query, #Reference<0.2121126444.1751646212.63871>, {:cql_query, "DROP KEYSPACE IF EXISTS lukla_dev;", [], :undefined, false, 100, :undefined, :one, :undefined, :undefined}}}
>   ** When State == :live
>   **      Data  == {:client_state, :cqerl_auth_plain_handler, :undefined, :undefined, {'cassandra', 9042}, :tcp, #Port<0.8647>, :undefined, :system, :infinity, "", :undefined, [{0, :undefined}, {1, :undefined}, {2, :undefined}, {3, :undefined}, {4, :undefined}, {5, :undefined}, {6, :undefined}, {7, :undefined}, {8, :undefined}, {9, :undefined}, {10, :undefined}, {11, :undefined}, {12, :undefined}, {13, :undefined}, {14, :undefined}, {15, :undefined}, {16, :undefined}, {17, :undefined}, {18, :undefined}, {19, :undefined}, {20, :undefined}, {21, :undefined}, {22, :undefined}, {23, :undefined}, {24, :undefined}, {25, :undefined}, {26, :undefined}, {27, :undefined}, {28, :undefined}, {29, :undefined}, {30, :undefined}, {31, :undefined}, {32, :undefined}, {33, :undefined}, {34, :undefined}, {35, ...}, {...}, ...], {[], []}, [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, ...], [], :hash, {{'cassandra', 9042}, [included_applications: [], keyspace: :system, num_clients: 2, query_timeout: 5000]}}
>   ** Reason for termination = 
>   ** {:"module could not be loaded", [{:re2, :compile, ['\'*(\?|:\w+)\'*(?:(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)'], []}, {:cqerl_cache, :lookup, 2, [file: '/mnt/svcs/lukla/deps/cqerl/src/cqerl_cache.erl', line: 58]}, {:cqerl_client, :live, 3, [file: '/mnt/svcs/lukla/deps/cqerl/src/cqerl_client.erl', line: 244]}, {:gen_fsm, :handle_msg, 8, [file: 'gen_fsm.erl', line: 483]}, {:proc_lib, :init_p_do_apply, 3, [file: 'proc_lib.erl', line: 247]}]}

My `.dockerignore` is:

```
_build
.git
node_modules
deps
priv/static
```

My `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM xerpa/ubuntu:v20190114

# Compile in prod mode by default
ARG MIX_ENV=prod

# .mix folder will be inside the project
ARG LUKLA_HOME=/var/www/lukla

ENV MIX_ENV=${MIX_ENV}
ENV LUKLA_HOME=${LUKLA_HOME}
ENV MIX_HOME=${LUKLA_HOME}/.mix

WORKDIR $LUKLA_HOME

RUN wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu/erlang_solutions.asc -O /erlang-solutions.asc \
    && echo deb https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/ubuntu artful contrib | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/erlang-solutions.list \
    && apt-key add /erlang-solutions.asc

RUN export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
    esl-erlang=1:20.3 \
    libboost-dev \
    libboost-system-dev \
    libboost-thread-dev \
    libgraphicsmagick-dev \
    libgtest-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    libphonenumber-dev \
    libgeocoding7 \
    libprotobuf-dev \
    libre2-dev \
    libtool-bin \
    libwebp-dev \
    build-essential \
    cmake \
    cmake-curses-gui \
    lsb-release \
    protobuf-compiler \
    openjdk-8-jre \
    locales \
    poppler-utils \
    elixir=1.6.5-1 \
    tzdata \
    && ln -fs /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/Sao_Paulo /etc/localtime \
    && dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN echo en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 | tee /etc/locale.gen
RUN echo locales locales/default_environment_locale select en_US.UTF-8 | debconf-set-selections
RUN echo locales locales/locales_to_be_generated multiselect en_US ISO-8859-1, en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8 | debconf-set-selections
RUN locale-gen

# Stuff that should be cached
COPY ./.credo.exs ./.credo.exs
COPY ./.formatter.exs ./.formatter.exs
COPY ./apps/lukla_web/mix.exs ./apps/lukla_web/mix.exs
COPY ./apps/magoo/mix.exs ./apps/magoo/mix.exs
COPY ./apps/yak/mix.exs ./apps/yak/mix.exs
COPY ./mix.exs ./mix.exs
COPY ./mix.lock ./mix.lock
COPY ./config ./config
COPY ./automation ./automation

RUN test -f ${MIX_HOME}/archives/hex*.ez || mix local.hex --force
RUN test -f ${MIX_HOME}/rebar || mix local.rebar --force

RUN mix hex.organization auth xerpa --key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
RUN mix deps.get
RUN mix deps.compile

COPY ./apps ./apps
COPY ./boot ./boot
COPY ./doc ./doc
COPY ./package ./package

RUN mix compile
RUN mix phoenix.digest apps/lukla_web/web/static/assets -o apps/lukla_web/priv/static
```

Comment: Try deleting all `*.beam` files for your applications and dependencies (including in the `_build` directory), and recompiling.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile and your docker ignore file? I suspect you are copying the `_build` folder to the container and the version used on that are different of the host machine. Try not copy that folder and compile it inside the container.

Comment: @legoscia I tried remove the `_build`, but now I get other errors, I edited my question with these ones.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto That's strange - somehow a new version of the compiler is being used even when compiling everything from scratch. I would check the asdf configuration - you can select a specific Elixir+OTP combination with `v1.6.5-otp-20`; see [this page](https://bobs-list.kobrakai.de/#version_v1.6) for available combinations.

Comment: @legoscia I thought about that, but I'm already using `1.6.5-otp-20` of Elixir, and 20.0 Erlang, I don't know what could I do, it's strange because even when I tried change the version of both I got the same error.
`

Comment: @MarcosTapajós I added my `.dockerignore`, I can't share my `Dockerfile` because it has some keys.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto remove the keys (or any other sensitive data), I would like to understand more about what you are doing to try help you.

Comment: @MarcosTapajós I added the `Dockerfile`

Comment: @FelipeAugusto have you ever tried a `mix clean` (or delete the `_build` before the compile? Another extra question, any reason to not use the official Elixir docker image?

Comment: I didn't, I'm just starting to develop in Elixir, I think this command would help too.  And this project is a huge project on my current company, I think they have an reason, but I don't know why.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto why are you copying stuff after the `mix deps.compile`? It might be replacing things that are not supposed to be replaced.

Comment: Wouldn't `mix.deps compile` compile just the dependencies? I would think `mix compile` is just for our own code.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto based on the dockerfile I don't see any reason why you can't use the official image. Also, doing that you will have more control on versions update since you can't trust that the apt source will always have the version that you need/want.

Comment: @FelipeAugusto yes, it will compile dependencies only. If you take a look, the latest message that you shared is complaining about a dependency. So, it might be replacing the compiled version with that copy.

Comment: @MarcosTapajós Thank you very much! that makes sense! I'm gonna try move to the official Elixir Docker image and if I do I'm gonna update my answer with that extra hint too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first error message indicates an outdated build, then to solve that I needed to:

```sh
rm -rf project/_build
```

And tried again the bootstrap, however it showed the second error, about the `re2` lib compiled with a different version, even deleting the `_build` and images didn't solve the issue, then I thought about compile the project (and libs, then try the bootstrap after):

```sh
mix compile
```

As mentioned by @Marcos Tapajós, I believe `mix clean` would work too.

Then my command worked:

```sh
./project bootstrap
```

I guess there are other place where the package was outdated on my machine.

Comment: Try `mix deps.clean` and `mix clean` before the `mix compile`.